# how to implement non-reference transparent data structure in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to implement a data structure that will give me a "signature" when I register to it and hence I can:

1. query if a signature exists or not
2. merge two of such DS while maintain the correct behavior
3. delete a given signature

probably a little bit vague, but it's easy to implement, say, in Java like the following:

```
class Sig {}

class DesiredDS<A> {
    HashMap<Sig, A> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Sig insertWithNewSig(A a) {
        Sig s = new Sig();
        map.put(s, a);
        return s;
    }
    // ...
    // merge will be only to merge to map and delete will be only to delete the key
}
```

but i scratch my head and can't figure out how to do that in Haskell with the property of reference transparency.

any good idea? probably an equivalent answer of this is: how can i generate a data structure in Haskell that can compare equal while I don't need to bother deciding it's value?

Comment: well you can do just the same - the only difference will be that you pass around the `HashMap` (or whatever structure you choose to hold your associations in Haskell) - now you can get fancy, put that in a structure of your own (~ `DesiredDS`), use a State-Monad(transformer) to hold the map for you, ...

Comment: What are these signatures supposed to be like? Large random numbers?

Comment: Sounds like `(Monoid v, Monad m) => StateT (HashMap Sig v) m a`, depending on your actual `merge` behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the simplest is to use something like

```
type Signature a = IORef (Maybe a)
```

for which you have the operations:

1. query if a signature exists or not

   ```
   live :: Signature a -> IO Bool
   live ref = isJust <$> readIORef ref
   ```
2. merge two of such DS while maintain the correct behavior

   (...what is "the correct behavior"?)
3. delete a given signature

   ```
   delete :: Signature a -> IO ()
   delete ref = writeIORef ref Nothing
   ```
4. create new signature

   ```
   insertNewSignature :: a -> IO (Signature a)
   insertNewSignature a = newIORef (Just a)
   ```
5. compare equal

   ```
   (==) :: Signature a -> Signature a -> Bool
   ```

And, although you didn't ask for it, presumably you actually want to be able not just to check whether a signature exists or not but also to recover the value from the signature, for which you have the operation

```
readIORef :: Signature a -> IO (Maybe a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an awful lot of options! If you're looking to make random signatures for uniqueness, I suggest using a [randomness monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.4.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html) to handle your random seed(s), and `StateT` to manage your `HashMap`. Something like this, roughly:

```
type Sig = -- Something big enough that's an instance of `Random`
newtype DS a = DS (HashMap Sig a)
insert :: (MonadRandom m, MonadState (DS a) m) => a -> m Sig
insert a = do
  ds <- get
  ds' <- HM.insert <$> getRandom <*> pure a
  put ds'
```

Answer (score -3):

Is it cheating to use unsafe I/O?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Lib where

import           Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import           Data.Monoid
import           Data.Unique (Unique)
import qualified Data.Unique as Unique
import           System.IO.Unsafe

newtype Registrar a =
  Registrar (Map Unique a)
  deriving (Eq, Monoid)

insert :: a -> Registrar a -> (Unique, Registrar a)
insert value (Registrar amap) =
  (u, Registrar (Map.insert u value amap))
  where
    u = unsafePerformIO Unique.newUnique

merge :: Registrar a -> Registrar a -> Registrar a
merge = (<>)

delete :: Unique -> Registrar a -> Registrar a
delete signature (Registrar amap) =
  Registrar (Map.delete signature amap)
```

Comment: Use IO or St.  IO is not evil.  Please don't use `unsafe*` on stackoverflow answers.

Comment: it's perfectly harmless here, friend

Comment: No, it's *not* perfectly harmless here. It breaks referential transparency here. I wouldn't go as far as @ThomasMDuBuisson, but I'd oppose such illegitimate uses of unsafe functions in general.

Comment: non-referential transparency is the name of the game here, friend

Comment: The non-referential transparency is an XY question. That's not the right way to do this! `unsafePerformIO` is a tool for building the low-level guts of frameworks that expose pure APIs, and for debugging. It's not for turning Haskell into Java.